# How to prevent from fbclid (facebook click ID) from polluting google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, facebook, google-analytics-spam

Whenever someone from Facebook clicks on my site's link. `fbclid` is appended to the actual link which pollutes the entire thing in google analytics.

For example say I have a page domain.com/contact and for every visitor visiting contact page, analytics would consider /contact but since facebook appends `fbclid` in analytics it would show /contact?fbclid=XXX

Because of this I would never know how many page views exactly /contact page received because /contact?fbclid=XXX is considered a different page and there are tons of /contact?fbclid=XXX in my analytics which makes it very hard for me to understand how many pageviews actually /contact received. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved easily in Google Analytics settings. Go to **Admin** -> **View settings** and add `fbclid` to **Exclude URL Query Parameters** input box:

[image]

Analytics will strip this parameter off from now on. As this is a view level setting, you might want to repeat it for all your views, where you find this parameter to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Create a content group for urls containing `/contact`, this will preserve the fbclid data in case it is needed for future reference. This method also allows you to create additional content groups for your entire website. Your traffic sources likely append additional parameters on other pages as well.